# Gatsby result from useStaticQuery is undefined

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have a variable that stores the results from a `useStaticQuery` call but when I `console.log` it, it's undefined. The query works fine in GraphiQL, so why isn't it working with `useStaticQuery`?

```
const {backgroundImages} = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allFile(
        filter: {extension: {regex: "/(png)/"}, relativeDirectory: {eq: "slider"}}
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            base
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(width: 10, quality: 10, webpOptions: {quality: 70})
              
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
console.log(backgroundImages) // undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're destructuring the result and asking for the key `backgroundImages` that does not exist on the result of your query.

This query would return a result similar to:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allFile": {
      "edges": [
        "node": .....
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

That means you cannot access the object `backgroundImages` by destructuring (`{...}`), but you can access `data`. If you try:

```
const {data} = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      ...
    }
  `)
console.log(data)
```

You should be able to see the log for the query.